# Different results for simple operations made with ranges or arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm working with `VBA` for a very long time and I have quite experience with it. However, sometimes, it still blow my mind with his whimsicalities... 
In order to make a file with some accessible functionalities to all of my work colleagues, I chose to made every calculations on a script.
To do so, I populate an array with some `double` data:

```
Dim DT01() As Double: ReDim DT01(1 To N03) As Double
Dim R As Long: R = 1: Dim N As Long: Dim P As Double
For x = 1 To N01
    N = SH01.Cells(x + 4, 15).Value: P = SH01.Cells(x + 4, 14).Value
    For y = 1 To N: DT01(R) = P: R = R + 1: Next y
Next x
```

The `DT01` array is quite long (`N03 = 495258`) and the previous routine populates the array just as I intended. I even made the following:

```
For x = 1 To 495258
    SH01.cells(x, 1).FormulaR1C1 = DT01(x)
Next x
```

to check if I made a mistake on the script to fill the array. This piece of code writes alright the first column of the sheet `SH01` with the right values of the array.

If I calculate the sum of the column, I got `292547224.4`, which is the right value. However, if I use `Application.Sum(DT01)` on `VBA`, I got `1535172.8`.
When I saw this, I tried to calculate other things and the results are always different:

```
'On Excel:
    =AVERAGE(A1:A495258) = 598,6
'On VBA:
    Application.Average(DT01) = 42.1

'On Excel:
    =MAX(A1:A495258) = 3622.7
'On VBA:
    Application.Max(DT01) = 186.8    

'On Excel:
    =COUNT(A1:A495258) = 495258
'On VBA:
    Application.Count(DT01) = 36506
```

When I saw the last result, I knew immediately I had to ask someone about this... Does anybody knows what's happening here??

**UPDATE:**

I tried to calculate the sum of the array with a `loop` through all it's terms:

```
Dim SIGMA As Double: SIGMA = 0
For x = 1 To UBound(DT01)
    SIGMA = SIGMA + DT01(x)
Next x
```

and I got the right result (`292547224.4`), so why I still got `1535172.8` with `Application.Sum(DT01)`?

Comment: Using : to join on same line as above makes the code flow difficult to follow. I do note you are looping to N01 not N03. I assume that is intentional?

Comment: It may be helpful to see how `N03` obtains its value.

Comment: @QHarr, you don't really need to follow the code. The second procedure I posted writes the first 495258 lines correctly.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs: `N03 = 495258`.

Comment: You fill to N01 not N03 - what size is N01?

Comment: @QHarr: `For x = 1 To N01` determines a certain `N` and then `For y = 1 To N` fills the array. The filling is correctly done because `N01*ΣN = N03`, but you don't have to check that. I already tested and the array is correctly filled.

Comment: Is the result you are quoting the result up to index 36506 if you sum?

Comment: Yes, @QHarr. Good thinking... The first 36506 elements sum exactly 1535172.8.

Comment: That is the problem It is hitting a limit for sum on an array.

Comment: You're probably right. However I don't find nothing to explain that on the internet... And how to fix it (eventually)...

Comment: you can write to the sheet and sum the range in the sheet

Comment: And interesting question indeed +

Comment: "whimsicalities" makes this an excellent post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an ideal answer so someone may flesh out with decent documentation. I find that SUM on an array in VBA only works to length 36506 (starting at 1).

You can however, write the array of values to a range and then pass that range reference to 
`Application.Sum` and get the correct values.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, i As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:A495258") 'A1 has value 1, A2 has 2 etc.

    Debug.Print "Application.Sum(rng) " & Application.Sum(rng)   '<==  122640490911
    Debug.Print " Application.Sum(Application.Transpose(rng.Value)) " & Application.Sum(Application.Transpose(rng.Value))   '<== 666362271

    Dim arr3()
    ReDim arr3(1 To 495258)
    For Each c In rng
        i = i + 1
        arr3(i) = c.Value
    Next

    Debug.Print " Application.Sum(arr3) with  arr3(1 To 495258) " & Application.Sum(arr3)
    Debug.Print "Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr3) " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(arr3)
End Sub
```

Or write your own custom 1d sum function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim arr3(), c As Range, rng As Range, i As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:A495258")
    ReDim arr3(1 To 495258)
    For Each c In rng
        i = i + 1
        arr3(i) = c.Value
    Next
    Debug.Print SumArray(arr3)
End Sub

Public Function SumArray(ByVal arr As Variant) As Variant ' double
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        SumArray = SumArray + arr(i)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I test this my limit is 34464. I'm not sure if this number is arbitrary or what, but I don't see anything in documentation about it either...

Comment: @dwirony What values did you use to populate the array? I started with 1 in A2, 2 in A2 etc upto 495258

Comment: Eventually I did exactly this (writing the array contents to a `xlVeryHidden` sheet, operating that range and deleting it in the final). However this makes the procedure very slow. I just checked your answer as useful and didn't accept it so far (only because I'm after another kind of solution).

Comment: @QHarr I used `RandBetween(1, 100)` down for 100,000 rows and populated the array based on that.

Comment: I'm just wondering if that impacts on length that can used? Doesn't seem to. Sticks at same point for me.

Comment: @QHarr Now when I tried with 495258 rows, I hit the limit of 36506 like you did. I don't see any pattern in the numbers, *shrugs*.

Comment: Wow! I tried an array with 1'000'000 entries and the `Application.Sum` sums only the first 16960 elements... I think the limit depends on the array size...

Comment: Excel 2016 64 bit here

Comment: There is definitely a size limitation. I just don’t know how to define it sensibly with sound logic.